# How to avoid the occurrences of "`" and "~" symbols in a string using Java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to avoid the occurrences of  "`" and "~" symbols in a string using Java.

Eg:

String: hi everyo`ne

output: invalid

---

String: hi ev~eryone

output: invalid

---

String: hi everyone

output: valid

---

String: hi ev`eryon~e

output: invalid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use java's [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String input;
boolean valid = input.matches("^[^`~]*$");
```

The regex means "any number of characters that are neither `` ` `` nor `~`"